# Is there a quick-reference card for HLSL (DX9 or DX11)?

Tags: directx, directx11, hlsl, directx9

Does anyone know of a DX9 or DX11 counterpart to the GLSL quick-reference card from Khronos?  The GLSL card is pages 8-11 [here](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengl44-quick-reference-card.pdf), and lists preprocessor directives, operators, types, and builtin variables and functions in a concise way.

I have looked here, on MSDN, and on Google results, including at the answers of [this earlier question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/773/51386).  The closest I have found are:

- [Cg tutorial Appendix E](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_appendix_e.html), but that only covers the functions.
- [Adam Sawicki's cheatsheet](http://www.asawicki.info/Download/Misc/DirectX_11_CheatSheet.pdf), p.14, which lists predefined variables, but nothing else.
- [Ogre's wiki page on HLSL](http://wiki.ogre3d.org/HLSL), which gives examples but not a reference.
- The [Ventuz shader node docs](https://www.ventuz.com/support/help/V4_05/NodeShaderHLSLShader.html), which are close but are Ventuz-specific.

Context (and blatant plug ;) ) - there will be a Shader Showdown fragment-shader live-coding competition at [Demosplash 2018](http://www.demosplash.org) in Pittsburgh in a few weeks.  I am helping organize and would like the competitors to have reference cards so that more people can feel comfortable participating.  The software in question is [Bonzomatic](https://github.com/gargaj/Bonzomatic), which supports GLSL, DX9, and DX11 fragment shaders.  I can't give the GLSL competitors an unfair advantage, so if I can't find an HLSL quick-reference I will have to also not provide the GLSL reference.

I know this question may be on the edge of on-topic and appreciate your help. 
 It is difficult to search for "quick-reference card" because "reference" materials are often very detailed (e.g., MSDN), and "cards" are more often hardware than paper in this context :) .  I have tried other search terms as well, but with limited success.

Comment: Another search term that might help / have fewer false positives is "cheat-sheet"

Comment: @DMGregory Indeed and thank you!  Sorry I forgot to mention in the question that I tried that as well.  I added a link to one "cheatsheet" document I found.  If I have to cobble together one from separate sources, I can.  However, my level of confidence is low since have written exactly zero lines of HLSL in my life :) .

Comment: There's not an official one, but one of the DirectX MVPs created one as part of [his book](https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0976613212/thezbuffer-20?creative=327641&camp=14573&link_code=as1). It's a little dated because it covers Direct3D 9 era shader assembly, but it's still useful for beginners. The publisher is out of business so you'll need to find the PDF via a search engine. BTW, the modern location of the Microsoft HLSL documentation is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn thanks for the tip!  I asked Sebastien on RG.  If I do wind up rolling my own, would you by any chance be willing to sanity-check it before I post it for the world?  I see you have significant experience in the field :) .